# Deprecated Functionality: crypt() Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am getting following error after installing a new module in application. How can i fix this error.

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Deprecated Functionality: crypt(): Supplied salt is not valid for DES. Possible bug in provided salt format
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem like your new module using `password_has` as uses a strong hash, generates a strong salt, and applies proper rounds automatically. password_hash() is a simple crypt() wrapper and compatible with existing password hashes which caused issue on PHP7.

Try to use `password_verify` instead